# NavigationService.navigate not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, nullpointerexception, navigationservice

At a login page, I checked for the validity and I made a simple condition:

```
if (everything is good)
{
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/implementationPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); 
}
```

Then comes an error that points to this method:

```
private void RootFrame_NavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
{
    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("page {0} failed, error: {1}", e.Uri.ToString(), e.Exception.StackTrace));
        e.Handled = true; 
        // A navigation has failed; break into the debugger
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
     }
}
```

Has anybody any idea why am I getting error?

Comment: Is the path correct? Where's implementationPage located in the folder structure? What is the error?

Comment: yes it was correct, i was missing the implementation for the onNavigatedTo() class.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Carlos,

After a lot of searching on the materials online

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Windows-Phone-7-Silverlight-Programming-Navigation-between-Pages.aspx

This came in very handy. I didn't quite utilize the onNavigatedTo function apparently